# Removing an item from a list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, iterator, listiterator

I've scoured this site (as well as the web) and for some reason cannot find an answer that works. Either I get an index out of bounds error, or the next part of my code won't execute. All I am trying to do is remove a item from a list in Java using an iterator. Here is my code:

```
public boolean remove(T item) {
    while (bag.iterator().hasNext()) {
        T i = bag.iterator().next();
            if (i.equals(item)) {
                bag.iterator().remove();
                return true;
            }
    }
  return false;
}
```

My iterator inherits from my "Bag" class obviously, but here it is as well:

```
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<T>() {
        private int current = 0;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current < size;
        }

        public T next() {
            return data[current++];
        }

        public void remove() {
            for (int i=current-1; i<size-1; i++)
                data[i] = data[i+1];
            size--;
        }
    };
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks guys!!

Clayton

Comment: An array isn't a List. You can't perform the same operations on the two different containers.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: @ajb Tags. An array is not a List and an Iterator is not a ListIterator, even if an Iterator can be used on a List.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi I see--I hadn't looked at the tags.  I've pretty much given up on expecting tags to have anything to do with the question anyway.

Comment: @AngeloAlvisi you may have given up but somehow knew exactly what I was talking about and answered the question perfectly, just as intended. So thanks, Jason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time you call `bag.iterator()`, you get a new `Iterator` object, not the same one you had before. You should get the iterator once, then use it through your loop:

```
public boolean remove(T item) {
    Iterator<T> iter = bag.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        T i = iter.next();
            if (i.equals(item)) {
                iter.remove();
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Your code has another issue: if you call `remove()` on your iterator before you call `next()`, your code will try to access `data[-1]`. You might want to put some protection code around that such as:

```
public void remove() {
    if(current > 0) {
        for (int i=current-1; i<size-1; i++)
            data[i] = data[i+1];
        size--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Jason. This is exactly what I was looking for. The bottom piece of code you corrected was also my professor's, who soon discovered that there was an error in his original coding so thanks again for bringing this to light.